# how to avoid float atomic add in opencl

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

I need to resolve a sparse matrix-vector multiplication in opencl, but the time i have when de kernel finish is very slow. I assume the slow time is because in the kernel exist atomic-add function.

This is de code of the kernel:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics : enable

void float_atomic_add(__global float *loc, const float f){
private float old = *loc;
private float sum = old + f;
while(atomic_cmpxchg((__global int*)loc, *((int*)&old), *((int*)&sum)) !=              *((int*)&old)){
    old = *loc;
    sum = old + f;
}
}



 __kernel void forward(__global int* col, __global int* row, __global float* data, __global int* symmLOR_X, __global int* symm_Xpixel,__global int*    symmLOR_Y, __global int* symm_Ypixel, __global int* symmLOR_XY,__global int*           symm_XYpixel, __global int* symmLOR_Z, __global int* symm_Zpixel, __global float* x, __global float* b){

  __private int i = get_global_id(0);
  __private int p, pixel,lor, LOR_Y, LOR_X, LOR_XY;
  __private int lor_z, pixel_z;
  __private float v;



  pixel = col[i]; // j
  v = data[i];
  lor= row[i];
  //b[lor] += v * x[pixel];
  float_atomic_add(&b[lor], v * x[pixel]);


  LOR_X = symmLOR_X[lor];
  p = symm_Xpixel[pixel];
  //b[LOR_X] += v * x[p];
  float_atomic_add(&b[LOR_X], v * x[p]);

  LOR_Y = symmLOR_Y[lor];
  p = symm_Ypixel[pixel];
  //b[LOR_Y] += v * x[p];
  float_atomic_add(&b[LOR_Y], v * x[p]);

  LOR_XY = symmLOR_XY[lor];
  p = symm_XYpixel[pixel];
  //b[LOR_XY] += v * x[p];
  float_atomic_add(&b[LOR_XY], v * x[p]);

  // do Z symmetry.
  lor_z = symmLOR_Z[lor];
  pixel_z = symm_Zpixel[pixel];
  //b[lor_z] += v * x[pixel_z];
  float_atomic_add(&b[lor_z], v * x[pixel_z]);

  LOR_X = symmLOR_X[lor_z];
  p = symm_Xpixel[pixel_z];
  //b[LOR_X] += v * x[p];
  float_atomic_add(&b[LOR_X], v * x[p]);

  LOR_Y = symmLOR_Y[lor_z];
  p = symm_Ypixel[pixel_z];
  //b[LOR_Y] += v * x[p];
  float_atomic_add(&b[LOR_Y], v * x[p]);

  LOR_XY = symmLOR_XY[lor_z];
  p = symm_XYpixel[pixel_z];
  //b[LOR_XY] += v * x[p];
  float_atomic_add(&b[LOR_XY], v * x[p]);

  }
```

To do that i use a Sparse matrix in a COO format.

Comment: Generally, OpenCL works better if you have larger independent pieces of work, so if you have more than one or two matrixes that you want to multiply, use a kernel for each matrix rather than spread the matrix over many kernels. As it stands, your code is simply serializing the matrix multiplication, so you essentially don't get much benefit at all from multiple kernels. There are possibly other methods that you could use, such as calculating a portion of the matrix only using atomic add in one dimension, or some such, but if possible, do a full matrix per kernel, and you'll see better result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now i try to make 8 multiplications  with different kernels instead of one.